# Focus controls on postback

Tags: jquery, validation, focus

I am using jquery validation to validate my c# code.
The problem is that any end user can remove the required="true" from DOM and the validations fails completely. To avoid this I added server validation for this(as it was the safest to ensure no DOM changes).there is one server validator per page

After validation I am not able to bring the control into the view.I added the `control.focus()`
but it only brings the cursor into the control but does not bring the control into the viewable area of the user. So if user has scrolled down there is no way for him to find where the validation was fired.

How can I bring the control into the viewable area of the user.

Comment: Is there no specific integration with C# that needs to be addressed separately to the the pure jQuery solution?

Comment: I looked for a similar solution. Like how can I prevent DOM Manipulation but did not get any good solution. So came to this as a possible fix